# Document not deallocated on window close?

Tags: macos, nswindow, nsdocument, document-based

I have a document-based application, and my NSDocument subclass and NSWindow subclass are not being deallocated when I close a window. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: you somewhere have a strong retain cycle.... hard to debug... have some details?

Comment: To give you a pointer and maybe help you decide what to add to your question: - i just went through the same problem: add deinit/dealloc to all your classes and print/NSLog "class name dealloced" and then look which class is not sending its dealloc message.